# Replace a image with JQuery

Tags: jquery, elementor

Does anyone have any insight on how to change an elementor image with jQuery?

```
$("imageID").attr("src","/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/F2.jpg")
```

Has no effect.

Comment: Did you add a # to your imageID? ex: $("#imageID").attr("src","/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/F2.jpg")

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You have an error in your Selector. To select an ID, you must include a `#`. E. G. `$("#imageID")`

Comment: The selector fine.  I have tested it with the .hide() / .show() methods

Comment: I notice the missing "#" after my post.  Even after adding the '#"  the elementor image is not being changed

Comment: Problem solved.  elementor puts the img in a DIV. When you are assigning a CSS ID in Elementor you are in fact assigning the ID to the DIV.  .$("#XXX img).attr. changes the image